# zsh command line editing problems when reverse-searching the history fixed by ctrl-l

Tags: fedora, zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh, line-editor

In zsh, using oh-my-zsh and the robby-russell theme, under Fedora Core 23, I noticed that when I reverse-searched for commands in the command history and tried to edit the results, the display would show the cursor at some incorrect position.

Usually, typing ctrl-l to reset the display would fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The answer turned out to be an incorrect setting for the environment variable 
LC_CTYPE.  putting the line

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```

in my .zshrc solved this problem for me.